# Wireshark does not show any interface to capture packets

Tags: networking, permissions, configuration, wireshark

I've installed Wireshark in Ubuntu 16.04 with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark
```

After program start, *Start Capture* and *Stop Capture* buttons are disabled. Even opening *Capture Options* window, I can't see any interfaces to capture packets from. They don't show even with menu *`Capture > Refresh Interfaces`*.

Where are all machine's interfaces?

**Edit:**

I also noticed there's a message in the main screen:

`Couldn't run /usr/bin/dumpcap in child process: Permission denied`

Comment: You have to run wireshark as root to see all interfaces. Just open terminal and write "sudo wireshark". You will have to enter password.

Comment: Can't run it with `sudo`. The output for `sudo wireshark` is  `No protocol specified`  /  `QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0`  /  `Aborted (core dumped)`

Comment: Try following these instructions: https://sathisharthars.wordpress.com/2014/06/04/running-wireshark-with-non-root-user-in-kali-linux/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you could run wireshark as root, it should be avoided.

Instead, try this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
```

Select `YES` to the question

Then add your user to newly created wireshark group with this

```
sudo adduser $USER wireshark
```

Finally log out, and log back in and you should be able to capture packets.

Comment: I was able to capture packets only if I enabled capture to non-superusers... If I select _`No`_ to question issued by `sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common`, even with my user in wireshark system group, I can see interfaces but can't capture through those.

Comment: @ThiagoRiderAugusto My bad, I added one step to the answer. Try select `YES` to the question

Comment: Selecting `YES` allows even users not in _wireshark_ group or just added users?

Comment: Just the user/users added to the group. (somebody correct me if I'm wrong)